# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AdmissionID'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database-connection, join

Server Error in '/' Application.

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AdmissionID'.

**Description:**

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AdmissionID'.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AdmissionID'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352418
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1406
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +140
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1481
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding(Boolean value) +9844021
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) +15
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.OnDataSourceViewChanged(EventArgs e) +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.SelectParametersChangedEventHandler(Object o, EventArgs e) +31
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.OnParametersChanged(EventArgs e) +20
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.UpdateValue(HttpContext context, Control control) +142
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.UpdateValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +36
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList) +257
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +589
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +23
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

My SQL Command is like this >> `SELECT * FROM [Bed] WHERE WardID = @WardID AND BedStatus = 'Available' AND BedNo NOT IN (SELECT BedNo FROM  [AdmissionDetail], [Admission] WHERE ([AdmissionDate] <= @AdmissionDate AND [DischargeDate] >= @DischargeDate AND AdmissionStatus <> 'Discharged' AND [AdmissionDetail]AdmissionID = [Admission]AdmissionID))`

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and using asp:DropDownList and asp:SqlDataSource to do this.
I have 4 table which is Admission, AdmissionDetail, Ward and Bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **dot** between `table alias` and `column name` in `where` clause

`..[AdmissionDetail].AdmissionID = [Admission].AdmissionID`

Also make a note of few points.

Always use proper `INNER JOIN` to join two table instead of old style commma separated join and keep the *filters* alone in `where` clause

Instead of `Not In` clause `Not exists` which may boost the performance and `NOT IN` will fail when `sub-query` returns any `NULL` values

```
SELECT *
FROM   [Bed] b
WHERE  WardID = @WardID
       AND BedStatus = 'Available'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   [AdmissionDetail]
                              INNER JOIN [Admission]
                                      ON [AdmissionDetail].AdmissionID = [Admission].AdmissionID
                       WHERE  b.bedno = BedNo
                              AND [AdmissionDate] <= @AdmissionDate
                              AND [DischargeDate] >= @DischargeDate
                              AND AdmissionStatus <> 'Discharged')
```